# Convert a string into a decimal number for use in query

Tags: php, wp-query

I have a meta box where a 'Case Result' CPT can be assigned a monetary value (e.g. $60 Million). I need to convert this into a decimal number for use as the `meta_key` in `WP_Query`.

I understand how to do the reverse (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#89888), but want to know if there's a reasonable approach to taking a '$60 Million' string and converting it to '60000000'.

My current query is below, which is re-run across multiple 'Attorney' pages (hence the `$attorney_name` for `terms`) to show the only cases they were responsible for. I'd like to order these posts by their monetary value in descending order, but I'm aware the current config (`meta_type` etc) won't work with the value in it's current string state. Any advice would be massively appreciated.

```php
    // Configure query
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'case-result',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                // Filter CPT's to display by taxonomy
                'field' => 'name',
                'taxonomy' => 'case-result-attorney',
                'terms' => $attorney_name,
            )
        ),
        // Sort CPT's by meta
        'meta_key' => 'case_claim_value',
        'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    ) );
```

Comment: Your post meta query appears to  have been inserted in the middle of a tax query, is this a full code snippet or has it been cut in half?

Comment: Hey Tom - messed it up during formatting. Just updated the query

Answer (score 1):

For decimal values, use `DECIMAL` as it says in the official `WP_Query` documentation:

> `‘meta_value‘` – Note that a `‘meta_key=keyname‘` must also be present in
>   the query. Note also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is
>   fine for strings (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g.
>   1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might
>   naturally expect). Use `‘meta_value_num‘` instead for numeric values.
>   You may also specify `‘meta_type‘` if you want to cast the meta value as
>   a specific type. Possible values are `‘NUMERIC’`, `‘BINARY’`, `‘CHAR’`,
>   `‘DATE’`, `‘DATETIME’`, `‘DECIMAL’`, `‘SIGNED’`, `‘TIME’`, `‘UNSIGNED’`, same as
>   in `‘$meta_query‘`. When using `‘meta_type’` you can also use
>   `‘meta_value_*’` accordingly. For example, when using DATETIME as
>   `‘meta_type’` you can use `‘meta_value_datetime’` to define order
>   structure.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

Comment: Are these able to be used as parameters in get_posts too? I've tried meta_type as DECIMAL but it doesn't seem to change the output of get_posts

Comment: `get_posts` is at its core a wrapper around `WP_Query`, all the parameters work for that reason because it's the same code that uses them. The main differences are that `get_posts` might specify slightly different defaults, the same way `get_pages` will change the default post type to `page` but they're all the same

Comment: if you're hoping that `get_posts` does not support that parameter, or it works differently, then no, that is not the problem and you'll likely have exactly the same issue with `WP_Query`.